# how to resolve "conflicts with" errors in d?

Tags: namespaces, d, conflict

I'm trying to compile some D. The code that I've written uses the `std.string` library as well as `std.algorithm`. One of my functions calls `indexOf` on a string: unfortunately, apparently there's also a `indexOf` function in `std.algorithm`, and the compiler doesn't like it:

```
assembler.d(81): Error: std.algorithm.indexOf!("a == b", string, immutable(char)).indexOf at /usr/share/dmd/src/phobos/std/algorithm.d(4431) conflicts with std.string.indexOf!(char).indexOf at /usr/share/dmd/src/phobos/std/string.d(334)
assembler.d(81): Deprecation: function std.algorithm.indexOf!("a == b", string, immutable(char)).indexOf is deprecated
```

How do I get around this? In C++ I could use the `::` to explicitly say what namespace I'm in... what about D?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to call `std.string.indexOf` explicitly, then do `std.string.indexOf(str, c)` instead of `indexOf(str, c)` or `str.indexOf(c)`.

Or you can use an alias:

```
alias std.string.indexOf indexOf;
```

If you put that inside the function where you're calling `indexOf`, then it should then consider `indexOf` to be `std.string.indexOf` for the rest of the function. Or if you put it at the module level, then it'll affect the whole module.

However, due to a [bug](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=6185), UFCS (Universal Function Call Syntax) doesn't currently work with local aliases, so if you put the alias within the function, you'll have to do `indexOf(str, c)` instead of `str.indexOf(c)`.

A third option is to use a selective import:

```
import std.string : indexOf;
```

With that import, only `indexOf` is imported from std.string, and when you use `indexOf`, it'll use the `string` version (even if you've also import std.algorithm). And you can even import std.string regularly in addition to the selective import to get the rest of std.string, and the selective import will still fix the conflict (in which case, it's really not that different from importing std.string and then aliases `indexOf`). However, due to a [bug](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=314), selective imports are always treated as public, so doing a selective import of `indexOf` in a module will affect every module that imports it (potentially causing new conflicts), so you may want to avoid it at this point.